# grep for text in *.odt or *.doc files?

Tags: libreoffice, grep

How can I search for *.odt or *.doc files that contain certain text in Ubuntu?

I use `grep -rl <text to search for>`, but this only works for text files.

Note: a solution that uses grep (such as searchmonkey) will not work because the *.doc or *.odt files have a special format.

From [How to search for strings inside files in a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198110/how-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-in-a-folder)

- Recoll wants to index my home directory, but I want to search *.odt
  files in specific directories; I couldn't figure out how to do that with
  this tool.
- Searchmonkey seems to be a GUI for grep, and as I mentioned, grep
  doesn't work on *.doc or *.odt files.
- Regexxer also has the same problem.

From [Searching through ODT documents without opening them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175429/searching-through-odt-documents-without-opening-them)

- Like Recoll, I couldn't figure out how to search *.odt files in specific directories with this tool.

Comment: Related: [How to “cat” or “less” a libreoffice writer .odt file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546765/how-to-cat-or-less-a-libreoffice-writer-odt-file)

Comment: I am trying to find all files that contain certain text.  I could recursively cat all files in a directory.  However, I noticed that doing cat on *.odt files does not list all of the words in the file, and it includes a lot of unprintable characters.  I guess this is why grep doesn't work either.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=899179&p=10272667#post10272667 and other posts in that thread for searching .odt files.

Comment: You can try searchmonkey and recoll according to these links, https://askubuntu.com/questions/198110/how-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-in-a-folder and https://askubuntu.com/questions/31869/how-to-search-pdf-files-by-their-metadata

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198110/how-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-in-a-folder)? Because that question is about searching through *ASCII* files while this one is about searching through binary file formats.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`catdoc` appears to work recursively for `.doc` files in 16.04: https://superuser.com/questions/330242/how-to-recursively-find-a-doc-file-that-contains-a-specific-word

There's no mention of `.docx` so you'll need to figure that one out yourself.

For `.ods` or `.odt` files, you could have the following script courtesy [kaibob @ ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=811714&p=8531314#post8531314):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*.od*" | while read i ; do
   [ "$1" ] || { echo "You forgot search string!" ; exit 1 ; }
   unzip -ca "$i" 2>/dev/null | grep -iq "$*"
   if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      echo "string found in $i" | nl
   fi
done
```

Let's say you call it "libre-search" and have [made it executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779951/how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-without-using-sh-or-bash-commands).

Then, running `libre-search your_string` should list files containing *your_string*. It will not list the string context.

`unzip -ca "$i" 2>/dev/null` takes care of unwanted content.
`grep -iq` makes the search case-insensitive.
`nl` numbers the output.

Comment: One could also convert ODT/S/P files to PDF with `unoconv` then use `pdfgrep`.

Comment: This looks promising.  I will try it and comment back.

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarto, your idea sounds good too.  In my particular case, I have hundreds of files, within a directory structure, so I wouldn't want to convert all of them. However, you should post your suggestion as an answer, because it may be useful to someone else searching for this topic.

Comment: @ DK Bose, your solution worked the best out of the ones I tried (from the alternate questions above).  I did experience some errors in the unzip process for some files, but that might be due to corrupt files.  I like the fact that your solution is command line based, it can work on an arbitrary directory, it can be scripted to search though directory trees, and that it does not require me to index all my files.

Comment: I've modified the code slightly to remove the unzip errors and to make the search insensitive.